# Binary Tree Right Side View: What is wrong of my code?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

The problem from:

https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-right-side-view/

Here is my code :

```
public class Solution {

    static int maxLevel = 0;

    public List<Integer> rightSideView(TreeNode root) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        rightViewUtil(root, 1, list);

        return list;
    }

    private void rightViewUtil(TreeNode root, int level, List list){

        if (root == null) return;

        if (maxLevel < level){
            list.add(root.val);
            maxLevel = level;
        }

        rightViewUtil(root.right, level + 1, list);
        rightViewUtil(root.left, level + 1, list);

    }

}
```

When I submit the code, it shows my code gives the wrong answer:

> Input:    {1,2} Output:   [2] Expected:   [1,2]

However, when I run the code in local with `main`,(I changed the class name in local)

```
TreeNode node  = new  TreeNode(1);
node.right = new TreeNode(2);
// node.left = new TreeNode(2);

List<Integer> list = new BinaryTreeRightSideView().rightSideView(node);

for (Integer i : list){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The output is `1 2` actually.

Comment: Are you sure that you are interpreting the input correctly? It's not clear to me how `{1, 2}` describes a "tree".

Answer (score 0):

This one was really puzzling, but the issue is that you've made `maxLevel` static.  As a result, the value was persisting through multiple tests.  Remove the `static` and your code passes the test.

In an independent run of the that test your code works just fine.  The issue is that `maxLevel` was already `1` when the test started which caused your code to not add the root node.

Answer (score 0):

int[] maxLevel = new int[] {0}; and pass it as a parameter to the util func.